# How to get data from indexeDB in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, indexeddb

I have a json response like this.

```
  {
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "name": "ABC",
      "Id": "1234",
      "address": "adthhyrr"    
    }
  }
}
```

In service.ts I am doing a request like this to get the response data.

```
     login_data: Object;
      db :any;
      constructor(){
         this.db = new AngularIndexedDB('TEST', 1);
      }
      public getResponseData() : Promise<any> {
          if(typeof(this.login_data) === "undefined") {
                return this.http.get('assets/response.json')
                .toPromise().then(res => {

                 this.login_data = res.json().response.data;
                 this.db.createStore(1, (evt) => {
                 let objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore('login', { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
                 objectStore.createIndex("keyname", "valuename", { unique: true });
                 console.log("db created login")
                 }).then(() => {

                 this.db.add('login', { keyname: 'loginresponse', valuename: JSON.stringify(this.login_data) }).then(() => {
                 console.log('login fields added');
                 }, (error) => {
                   console.log('error is...'+error);
                 });

                });

          return this.login_data;
        }).catch(this.handleError);
    } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.login_data);
   }
  }
```

In the above method after getting response i am creating objectstore and storing the jsonresponse in to login table.

Now i want to first get all the login response data and then i want to show all in html page.So for getting data i am doing like this.

```
getAllData() { 
       var data =  this.db.getAll('login').then((login) => {
        console.log("login from index"+login);
       }, (error) => {
      console.log('login'+error);
   });
  return JSON.parse(data);
 }
```

If i wil not use **JSON.parse in return statement** then i am getting error 
**You need to use the createStore function to create a database before you query it!**
And i am calling this getAllData method in one component.ts like this

```
   data=[];
  ngOnInit(){
 this.data= this.loginService.getAllData();
}
```

But i am getting syntax error **Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**.
Can anyone please help me how to get data from indexedDB.

Comment: Where do you get the Unexpected token? How does the response from the indexedDB look like? Also. It is difficult to read your code the way it is formatted. Is it possible to clean it up, making it easier to read?

Comment: In console i am getting Unexpected token.And response from indexedDB is [object Object]. @John

Comment: why i am getting this error like You need to use the createStore function to create a database before you query it!  .Is it like to get data from indexedDB everytime i have to create a db but it is already exist .?? @John

Comment: I think you need to write `return Promise.resolve(data)` in your `getAllData()`-method

Comment: I am not familiar with the AngularIndexedDB library, but if you use the built in `IDBDatabase` browser library, you always need to open the DB (even if it exists, because it may have been closed). So check if it exists, and then create it if not

Comment: @John i am not sure about IDBDatabase. am using Angular2IndexedDB